# Dividing finite numbers by infinite numbers

Tags: soft-question

I am no great mathematician but I have a question which I can't seem to find a answer for. How can one divide a finite by a infinite number? For example if you have a circle with a circumference of exactly 40 to get the diameter of that circle you divide 40 by π. However if pi is infinite how are we able to obtain a value for the diameter?

Comment: The value is just $\frac{40}{\pi},$ and that is the exact value.

Comment: $\;\pi\;$ isn't, and can't be, infinite. It is a very definite, finite number, just like $\;1,2,0.56\;$ or $\;1000\;$ . Now, do you have any idea how would *you* want to define "an infinite number"? I mean, what is that?

Comment: Would I be correct in calling π an irrational number instead? @Timbuc

Comment: @Dan $\pi$ is irrational, and finite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you seem to be confused with your concepts. There is no *infinite* real number. What you are calling "infinite" is actually "having infinite decimal expansion".

Also, note that you may be comfortable with division by other numbers which have infinite decimal expansion: take $\frac{4}{3}$ for instance. Even simpler is division by $\frac{1}{3}$:  which is simply multipying by $3$.

If you have a problem with operating with irrational numbers, there is no way I could (decently) tell you what are you exactly doing when you operate them without getting "technical". I can give you some intuitive/geometric description like: $\frac{a}{b}$ is the number $x$ for which the rectangle with sides $x$ and $b$ has area $a$... but that is sort of cheating. To understand operating with these numbers, you need to know how real numbers are defined (search for Dedekind Cuts, for instance. It is a way of constructing them.)

Answer (score 1):

> However if $\pi$ is infinite, how are we able to obtain a value for the diameter?

That really depends on what do you mean by "a value". Is $329$ a value? What about $3.9$? What about $\sqrt2$? What about $2\sqrt 2$? If you are convinced that $\sqrt 2$ is a "value" (whatever that means), then $\pi$ should be a value. It might seem exotic since we are using a greek letter to represent that thing, but it's still a value. If you want you can use $\star$ to represent pi.

I think what really confuses you is this: how do I get the numerical value of $\pi$ or $\frac{40}{\pi}$? That would be a different subject. See [Approximations of $\pi$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80)